# ajax popup alert working but sound not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

this is ajax version when inside text file something change then it popup alert 
it working well . but i also would like to sound alert when popup 
i tried and search hours but i couldn't found which working together with my ajax script.

```
<audio id="audiotag1" src="Ring04.wav" preload="auto"></audio>


<script language="javascript">

var previous = "";

setInterval(function() {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            if (ajax.responseText != previous) {
                document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
                sleep(1);
                alert("file changed!");

                previous = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
    };
    ajax.open("POST", "xxx.txt", true); //Use POST to avoid caching
    ajax.send();
}, 3000);

</script>
```

Comment: have you invented the `sleep` function? I only know setTimeout...

Comment: sorry sleep(1) function can ignore..